# Calabash/cucumber not recognizing labels

Tags: ios, cucumber, calabash, gherkin

I think I am missing something obvious. I followed the fast-track instructions found [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios) 
 . I did no extra configuration.

I run the cucumber command on a simple test on a view's label I set in my project. It fails... I then execute in the terminal:

```
calabash-ios console
start_test_server_in_background
query("view")
```

I do not see the label I set in my project in the view hierarchy. If I subsequently re-build my project (while in the console) and run query("view") again, I see the labels that were missing before. What's going on here? Why do I have to build the project while in the console to see the current state of the project? What are the reasons why the console and cucumber command (may not / do not) recognize these labels?

Comment: Are you sure you are building for the same target as you are starting the simulator/console for? It would help if you share how you build and how you run the console. When starting the console you can include both apk location as well as what simulator to use. like so APP_BUNDLE_PATH=Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp-cal.app DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5s (7.1 Simulator)' calabash-ios console

Comment: I am certain of building for the same target. I open the 01_launch.rb file and setting APP_BUNDLE_PATH to the calabash target's derived data bundle path, then yes I tried that. Before doing this I am building the project in XCode under the ProjectName-cal scheme. I run the console without setting bundle path or device target as you specify; I tried it and it seems to work in that context after setting the APP_BUNDLE_PATH;  I get an error when running the cucumber command however that shows up right after the Scenario: line: "no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)"

Comment: It might be related to an error on calabash https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/issues/102 at least the error report sounds similar.

Comment: `no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)"` If this is occurring when you execute cucumber, then it is different from the run_loop/issue 102.  If you continue to have problems with cucumber, please ask another question or make a github issue.  Thanks! jjm

Comment: It occurs on execution of cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Xcode 6, `instruments` no longer reinstalls applications on the simulator.  My best guess is that you built and ran on the simulator a version that did not contain the labels.  Then you added the labels on the ObjC/Swift side.  You might have built the project, but not run.  Well, you may have run - I will get to that in a moment.  When you went to the console you expected to be able to query for the labels.

It is not clear to us when the `instruments` process decides it should re-install a .app on the target simulator.  Sometimes it seems to, but most times it does not - it is not a behavior I am interested in understanding.

It is very easy to find yourself testing against a stale binary.

In my workflows, I usually reset the simulator before running my tests.

```
$ bundle exec calabash-ios sim reset
```

This forces `instruments` to install the most recent version of my app.

Typically, I use build scripts to ensure that I am working with the right version of the .app.

- https://github.com/jmoody/briar-ios-example/blob/master/Briar/sim-prepare.sh
- https://github.com/jmoody/animated-happiness/blob/master/chou/build-sim-cal.sh